# ¿Cómo corregir el error "TypeError: Cannot set properties of null(setting 'id') al intentar volver a actualizar un registro?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material

Tengo la siguiente tabla en donde el campo **descripcion** es editable, al momento de realizar una actualizacion y darle click en el boton de editar lo hace sin problema y te manda el mensaje de éxito, pero el problema es cuando quiero volver a actualizar la descripcion de cualquiera de los registros, no hace nada y en la consola del navegador marca el error

> core.js:4442 ERROR TypeError: Cannot set properties of null (setting
> 'id')

Tengo que volver a cargar la pagina para que vuelva a hacer el update sin error, en el campo **descripcion**  uso la propiedad **keyup** para obtener lo que se ingrese en el input y obtener el id de la fila donde se esta haciendo el update

este es el html donde esta la tabla

```
       <mat-expansion-panel>
                <button mat-raised-button class="buttonUpdate" color="primary"
                    (click)="obtenerProductos()">Actualizar
                    <mat-icon>update</mat-icon>
                </button>
                <mat-expansion-panel-header>
                    <mat-panel-title class="text">
                        Productos
                    </mat-panel-title>
                </mat-expansion-panel-header>
                <div class="scrollme">
                    <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSourceProd" class="mat-elevation-z8">

                        <ng-container matColumnDef="id">
                            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> ID  </th>
                            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.id}} </td>
                        </ng-container>

                        <ng-container matColumnDef="descripcion">
                            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> DESCRIPCIÓN </th>
                            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
                                <mat-form-field class="example-form-field">
                                    <input matInput type="text" [value]="element.descripcion"
                                        (keyup)="changeValueDescTipo($event.target,element)"
                                        [disabled]="!element.editable">
                                </mat-form-field>
                            </td>
                        </ng-container>

                        <ng-container matColumnDef="botonEdit">
                            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> EDITAR </th>
                            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
                                <button mat-icon-button color="primary" (click)="actualizarProd(element,tipoProductoModelo)">
                                    <mat-icon>edit</mat-icon>
                                </button>
                            </td>
                        </ng-container>

                        <ng-container matColumnDef="botonDelete">
                            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> ELIMINAR </th>
                            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
                                <button mat-icon-button color="warn"
                                (click)="eliminarProductos($event.target,element)">
                                    <mat-icon>delete</mat-icon>
                                </button>
                            </td>
                        </ng-container>

                        <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumnsProd"></tr>
                        <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumnsProd">
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
                <mat-paginator #paginatorCatalogos [pageIndex]="0" [pageSize]="5" [pageSizeOptions]="[5]"
                    showFirstLastButtons>
                 </mat-paginator>
            </mat-expansion-panel>
```

Component.ts

```
    displayedColumnsProd: string[] = ['id', 'descripcion', 'botonEdit', 'botonDelete'];
    idSelecc: any;
    productoDescripcion: any;
    tipoProducto: Producto[] = [];
    tipoProductoModelo: Producto = new Producto();
    
    dataSourceProd: any;
    obtenerProductos() {
    this.productService.obtenerProducto().subscribe(response => {
      if (response.data.length == 0) {
        Swal.fire({
          icon: 'error',
          text: 'Sin datos '
        })
      } else {
        this.tipoProducto = response.data;
        this.dataSourceProd = new MatTableDataSource(this.tipoProducto);
        this.dataSourceProd.paginatorCatalogos = this.paginatorCatalogos;
      }

    });
    }
    
    //obtiene el valor de la descripcion 
    changeValueDescTipo(e: any, row: any) {
       this.idSelecc = row.id;
       this.productoDescripcion = e.value;
    }
    
    actualizarProd(element: any,tipoProductoModelo: Producto) {
    if (element.editable) {
      element.editable = false;
      if (this.productoDescripcion == null) {
        Swal.fire({
          icon: 'error',
          title: 'Error',
          text: 'No hay registros modificados'
        });
      } else {
        tipoProductoModelo.id = this.idSelecc;
        tipoProductoModelo.descripcion = this.productoDescripcion;
        this.productService.actualizarProducto(tipoProductoModelo).subscribe(data => {
          tipoProductoModelo = data;
          
          this.productoDescripcion = null;
          Swal.fire({
            icon: 'success',
            title: 'Éxito',
            text: 'Registro actualizado correctamente'
          });
        });
      }

    } else {
      element.editable = true;
    }
  }
```

en las lienas que marca el error en el navegador, esta esta linea del component.ts

> this.tipoProductoModelo.id = this.idSelecc;

y en el html marca la linea

> <button mat-icon-button color="primary"
> (click)="actualizarProd(element)">

entiendo que el error puede ser de que el **idSelecc** este llegando vacio la segunda vez que se intenta actualizar  y por eso marca
**Cannot set properties of null (setting 'id')**, pero entonces como vuelvo a recuperar el id de la fila que quiero volver a actualizar?

Comment: El problema no es que `idSelecc` sea `null`. El problema es que `tipoProductoModelo` es `null`. Te está diciendo que no puedes setear el campo ID de NULL. `this.tipoProductoModelo.ID` <- ahí está el campo id que intentas setear, hacer esto: `this.foo = null` no tiene ningún problema, se hace constantemente para "limpiar" variables. `null.foo = bar` es problemático, `null` no tiene atributos de ningún tipo. El mensaje de error es claro al respecto, el objeto al que intentas asignarle un `id` está a null.

Comment: Este es un error muy básico, mira bien lo que estás usando en la función de actualizar. Qué es tipoProductoModelo? Luego asignas un `this`a otro `this`? Tienes doble if? Ya no hace sentido y empieza a parecer más JS que TS , empezaría por limpiar y ordenar el código así como usar solamente nombres en español o inglés para variables/funciones/etc.

Comment: @René, tipoProductoModelo hace referencia al Modelo Producto, lo declaro para setear los valores a los atributos id y descripc, ya que el método actualizarProducto() del service, recibe como parametro el modelo Producto y el update se hace por id,hago doble if donde valido si el valor ingresado en la descripcion es igual a null, ya que si no agrego esa validacion, al momento de dar click en el boton editar se habilita el input de la descripcion y si le vuelvo a dar click en el boton editar sin meter un valor, truena y sale error 404, porq llama al servicio y detecta que no se ingreso un valor

Comment: @René de que otra forma puedo controlar eso, para no tener ese doble if, es decir, que al dar click en el boton editar se habilita el input para ser modificado y si no se ingresa nada y se le vuleve a dar click en el boton de editar se vuelva a bloquear la edicion por asi decirlo, pero cuando si se ingrese algo se llame al servicio para el update

Comment: @René actualice la pregunta, lo modifique asi y ya no me manda ese error, yame deja volver a actualizar cualquier registro, es correcto de esa forma o puede haber una mejor?